# help with chain rule

Tags: calculus, derivatives

$$
\begin{align}
D(4x+x^{-5})^{1/3}&=\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)\left(4x-x^{-5}\right)^{\frac{1}{3}-1}D\left(4x+x^{-5}\right)\\
&=\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)\left(4x-x^{-5}\right)^{-2/3}\left(4-5x^{-6}\right)\\
&=\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)\left(4x-\frac{1}{x^5}\right)^{-2/3}\left(4-\frac{5}{x^6}\right)\\
&=\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)\left(\frac{4x^6}{x^5}-\frac{1}{x^5}\right)^{-2/3}\left(\frac{4x^6}{x^6}-\frac{5}{x^6}\right)\\
&=\cdots
\end{align}
$$
([Source](https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/~kouba/CalcOneDIRECTORY/chainrulesoldirectory/ChainRuleSol.html#SOLUTION%201))

How does $ (\frac{1}{3}) (4x + \frac{1}{x^5})^{-\frac 2 3}$ change to $(\frac{1}{3}) (4x^6 + x^{-5})^\frac{2}{3}$ ? I was guessing $4x$ was multiplied to $x^5$ but how the second fraction didn't change (to $\frac{x^5}{x^{10}}$)?

Comment: Where do you see such thing in the given link? I don't.

Comment: Is on the solution 4 where they start to simplify the expression

Comment: which part of the formula do you mean?

Comment: how does $(\frac{1}{3}) (4x + \frac{1}{x^5})^{-\frac 2 3} (4-\frac{5}{x^6})$ change to 
 $(\frac{1}{3}) (\frac{4x^6}{x^5} + \frac{1}{x^5})^{-\frac 2 3} (\frac{4x^6}{x^6}-\frac{5}{x^6})$

I mean how $ (4x + \frac{1}{x^5})$ could change to $(\frac{4x^6}{x^5} + \frac{1}{x^5})$ without affect $\frac{1}{x^5}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're reading the text differently than it's written. Starting with the line you're referencing, I see

$$
\begin{align}
&=\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)\left(\color{blue}{4x}+\frac{1}{x^5}\right)^{-\frac{2}{3}}\left(4-\frac{5}{x^6}\right)\\
&=\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)\left(\frac{4x^6}{\color{red}{x^5}}+\frac{1}{x^5}\right)^{-\frac{2}{3}}\left(\frac{4x^6}{x^6}-\frac{5}{x^6}\right)
\end{align}
$$

This is a valid operation because we can multiply the $\color{blue}{4x}$ term from the first line by ${x^5}/{x^5}=1$ without changing its value:

$$
4x=4x\cdot\frac{x^5}{x^5}=\frac{4x^6}{x^5}
$$

Comment: Now i understand thank you